# Unable to cite with ``et al.'' Springer Latex template (sn-jnl class)

Tags: apacite, springernature

When set documentclass
`\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}% APA Reference Style` ,
I want cite with short authors at any place, but this template at first place isn'n!
[image]

the code:

```
\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}% APA Reference Style 

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom



\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}


\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}


\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}


\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

\cite{bib1} 

\cite{bib1} 
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}%
\end{document}
```

the bib file

```
@article{bib1,
  author        = "Campbell, S. L. and Xall, P. B. and Gear, C. W.",
  title         = "The index of general nonlinear {D}{A}{E}{S}",
  journal       = "Numer. {M}ath.",
  volume        = "72",
  number        = "2",
  pages         = "173--196",
  year          = "1995"
}
```

My Overleaf project is [enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/2535839552zpcsmvkxprfr#2aaf6e)

Comment: Instead of posting a link to your project, please add a code with a minimal example that reproduces your problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the `sn-apa` option is passed to the `sn-jnl` document class, the `apacite` citation management package is loaded with the option `natbibapa`; in addtion, the `apacite` bibliography style is loaded. Taken together, the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style implement the APA6 formatting guidelines for bibliographies and citation call-outs.

What you've encountered is not a flaw but a *purposeful design feature* of the APA6 formatting guidelines for citation call-outs: Unless a publication has *six or more authors*, all authors are listed the first time a piece is cited; only from the second citation onward is the citation call-out abbreviated. (For publications with six or more authors, the list of authors shown in the citation call-outs is truncated to "FirstAuthor et al." immediately.)

If you can't stand this feature, you shouldn't employ the `sn-apa` document class option.