Cant compile document using \documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl} in overleaf
I have recently completed my paper and springer provided me this template \documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl} to use and i am unable to view the bibliography section, my file is updated properly and it is compiling everything else but not the biliography sn.bib file, i am trying since a month and no solutions have helped yet,i am working online on overleaf, i am losing my mind over it. Please help.

It's quite possible you have an error preventing the bibliography being generated but if you show no input, no output, and no error message, noone can help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

an sn-jnl example including a bibliography is here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702414/unable-to-cite-with-et-al-springer-latex-template-sn-jnl-class  If you get an error make a small example and show the error that you get/
